# Android 4.3.1: Take a picture in a service

Tags: android, image, service, camera

I'm working on an Open Source device manager, but having an issue with one security feature that allows users to take pictures from the camera if the phone is stolen. Everything works great in the Emulator, but on a Nexus 4 running Android 4.3.1, I get the following error (including the debug printouts):

```
    12-20 10:05:28.083: D/HelperService(22358): HERE0
    12-20 10:05:28.354: D/HelperService(22358): HEREA
    12-20 10:05:28.354: D/HelperService(22358): HEREB
    12-20 10:05:28.374: D/HelperService(22358): HEREC
    12-20 10:05:28.374: D/HelperService(22358): HERED
    12-20 10:05:28.644: D/HelperService(22358): HERE2
    12-20 10:05:28.644: D/HelperService(22358): HERE11
    12-20 10:05:28.654: I/Choreographer(22358): Skipped 33 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    12-20 10:05:30.656: D/AndroidRuntime(22358): Shutting down VM
    12-20 10:05:30.656: W/dalvikvm(22358): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x416287c0)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358): java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1145)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1090)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at com.nowsci.odm.HelperService$2$1.run(HelperService.java:271)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
    12-20 10:05:30.676: E/AndroidRuntime(22358):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Below is the code. I know it's somewhat ugly but I've just been trying to get this working vs unifying the try/catches, and consolidating camera opens, etc.

```
    public class HelperService extends Service {

    ...

        private SurfaceHolder sHolder;
        private Camera mCamera;
        private Parameters parameters;

        ...

        // For API 14 and newer
        public class CamCallback implements Camera.PreviewCallback {
            public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d(TAG,"HERE1");
                /*
                Handler handler = new Handler();
                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                        //camera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                    }
                }, 2000);
                */
            }
        }

        ...

        private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        ...

            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                ...

                if (message.equals("Command:FrontPhoto") || message.equals("Command:RearPhoto")) {
                    boolean cont = true;
                    if (message.equals("Command:RearPhoto")) {
                        Log.d(TAG,"HERE0");
                        try {
                            mCamera = Camera.open();
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        cont = false;
                        } finally {
                        if (mCamera != null) {
                                Log.d(TAG,"HEREA");
                            mCamera.stopPreview();
                                Log.d(TAG,"HEREB");
                            mCamera.release();
                                Log.d(TAG,"HEREC");
                            mCamera = null;
                                Log.d(TAG,"HERED");
                        }
                        }
                        try {
                            mCamera = Camera.open();
                        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        cont = false;
                        }
                    } else {
                        int cameraCount = 0;
                        Camera.CameraInfo cameraInfo = new Camera.CameraInfo();
                        cameraCount = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
                        for (int camIdx = 0; camIdx < cameraCount; camIdx++) {
                            Camera.getCameraInfo(camIdx, cameraInfo);
                            if (cameraInfo.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
                                try {
                                    mCamera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                cont = false;
                                } finally {
                                if (mCamera != null) {
                                    mCamera.stopPreview();
                                    mCamera.release();
                                    mCamera = null;
                                }
                                }
                                try {
                                    mCamera = Camera.open(camIdx);
                                } catch (RuntimeException e) {
                                Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                                cont = false;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (cont) {
                        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
                            Log.d(TAG,"HERE2");
                            CamPreview camPreview = new CamPreview(context, mCamera);
                            camPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(camPreview);
                            CamCallback camCallback = new CamCallback();
                            mCamera.setPreviewCallback(camCallback);
                            mCamera.startPreview();
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                                    Log.d(TAG,"HERE12");
                                }
                            }, 2000);
                            Log.d(TAG,"HERE11");
                        } else {
                            // Pre-android 4.0
                            Log.d(TAG,"HERE3");
                            SurfaceView sv = new SurfaceView(context);
                            sHolder = sv.getHolder();
                            sHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
                            try {
                                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(sHolder);
                                parameters = mCamera.getParameters();
                                mCamera.setParameters(parameters);
                                mCamera.startPreview();
                                Handler handler = new Handler();
                                handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
                                    }
                                }, 2000);
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                ...
```

The offending code above is this:

```
    Log.d(TAG,"HERE2");
    CamPreview camPreview = new CamPreview(context, mCamera);
    camPreview.setSurfaceTextureListener(camPreview);
    CamCallback camCallback = new CamCallback();
    mCamera.setPreviewCallback(camCallback);
    mCamera.startPreview();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
            Log.d(TAG,"HERE12");
        }
    }, 2000);
    Log.d(TAG,"HERE11");
```

I found this as another solution here on StackOverflow for taking a picture in a service for Android 4.0 and above (most solutions focus on pre-4.0). As stated, works fine in the Emulator, but not on a device. Manifest includes the expected:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Ideas?

Thanks.